# ubuntu 12.04 stopped showing every usb devices

Tags: 12.04, usb

Ubuntu was running perfectly, suddenly my internal HDD partitions (except file system) and partitions of external HDD disappeared. I was able to mount the partitions of internal HDD via disk utility, but I couldn't find the external HDD. I tried Gparted partition editor and it couldn't find the device. I tried my HP flash drive and found that all the USB devices were not shown up.

Here is the result of lsusb

```
:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0230 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 3D Optical Mouse
```

Comment: Check if the hardware and kernel components are responding when you plug a device. To do this, see the last few lines of output of the command `dmesg` as soon as you plug the device in. Post the output here, so we try to figure out what the problem is.